# Can I initialize a 2D string array to a specific string in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to initialize whole 2d array to a specific word say "word".

i.e. Every index has value of "word".

I want to use some function without traversing whole array.

I can't find any help in this regard.

Comment: I'm happy that you have things that you want to do. I'm rooting for you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic constructor or method to do this for you. That's likely because doing it yourself is trivial.

1D:

```
string[] values = new string[100];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    values[i] = "word";
```

2D:

```
string[,] values = new string[100,100];
for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
        values[i,j] = "word";
```

Comment: Ok so there is no constructor. Actually we can do it in C, so that makes me  think, maybe we can do it in c# too. So nice of you sir

Comment: @MuhammadAbubakr You can also do it in Python, or any number of other languages. But you asked about C#, which the only way I've ever seen is to use `Enumerable.Repeat` to create the array. That method is stupidly slow, though, not to mention overkill, so no one would ever recommend it.

Comment: you could use enumerable and linq to reduce it though - `Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat("word", 100).ToArray(),100).ToArray()` - or something like that. Bit pointless if you ask me though.

Comment: @will Check the comment immediately above you. Yes, you can use `Enumerable.Repeat` to initialize an array, but it can be anywhere from 4x to 20x slower than the `for-loop` method. (And that benchmark was only for 1D arrays.) It's not worth the performance hit just to reduce the line count.

Comment: @Abion47 i wasn't advocating it! I know it's slow - i only do it where it's convenient and speed is not a concern.

Comment: @will Even where convenience is a greater concern than speed, I still would prefer not to even mention `Enumerable.Repeat` as an option. Not only is it ridiculously slow, it also teaches the programmer to abuse LINQ by using it in circumstances where it is entirely overkill.